# Django Form request method is always GET, even method=“POST” is mentioned in HTML template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Please help me with this query. I have a project to work on...
Thanks!!

HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Views.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcDa0.png)

Comment: Will you reload Views.py? I cannot see anything.

Comment: yeah now you can see it

Answer (score 0):

You should add "action" attribute to your form so that the server can choose where to post the data. Add this attribute to your form tag:

```
action="{% url 'url_name' %}"
```

url_name here is the name in urlpatterns to receive a request from the form

For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('url_name/', views.index, name = 'url_name'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Views:**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Valid")
        student = Studentform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if student.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            student.save() # <== HERE 
            return HttpResponse('File uploaded successfully')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Not uploaded')
    else:
        student = Studentform()
    return render(request, 'name_of_your_upload.html', {'student': student})
```

**Template:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ student.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: only save button is visible other components are not visible..

Comment: i updated the answer ,add "student.save()"